# node-gyp rebuild error while installing node_xslt on Mac

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, npm

I have tried to install node_xslt but couldn't fix the issue, here is all I have done : updating homebrew, node.js, npm, deleting .node-gyp, ...

Please help me...

Thank you in advance.

```
npm install node_xslt

> node_xslt@0.1.9 preinstall /Users/David/node_modules/.staging/node_xslt-4c6485e9
> node-gyp rebuild
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node_xslt/node_xslt.o
../node_xslt.cc:18:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
    HandleScope handlescope;
                ^
/Users/David/.node-gyp/6.9.2/include/node/v8.h:915:13: note: declared protected here
  V8_INLINE HandleScope() {}
            ^
../node_xslt.cc:19:30: error: member reference type 'Persistent<v8::Value>' is not a pointer; did you mean to use '.'?
    Local<Object> obj = value->ToObject();
                        ~~~~~^~
                             .
../node_xslt.cc:19:32: error: no member named 'ToObject' in 'v8::Persistent<v8::Value, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Value> >'
    Local<Object> obj = value->ToObject();
                        ~~~~~  ^
../node_xslt.cc:26:17: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'v8::HandleScope'
    HandleScope handlescope;
                ^
/Users/David/.node-gyp/6.9.2/include/node/v8.h:915:13: note: declared protected here
```

Comment: It installs OK for me on node v0.10.48. No luck with anything newer.

Comment: Thanks it works I did :
`sudo n 0.10.48`.